# How to forward packets at TCP level by using iptables?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssl, iptables

Suppose I have two local machines A and B(Ubuntu), and there is also a remote server C. Originally, through RESTful API, I can call `GET https://domain_of_C/resources` directly from **machine A** to get some resources on **remote server C**

Now the requirement is that I need to first call **machine B** at 192.168.1.2(B's IP address) by:`GET https://192.168.1.2/resources`, and then **B** should help **A** forwarding everything to the **remote server C**, as well as getting the response back from **C** to **A**. **Machine B should blindly pass through the packets, including the SSL packets.**

My question is that how do I use `iptables` on **machine B** to achieve this? By far I have used:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1   #enable ip forwarding

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE   #ip masquerade

#forward everything to 443 port on the remote server
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination ip_of_remote_server:443
```

After using these commands on B, if I use `GET http://192.168.1.2/resources`(HTTP, not HTTPS), it works, meaning that I can successfully access the resources on the remote server. However, it is not working with the HTTPS `GET https://192.168.1.2/resources`

I don't know if I should actually call **B** a proxy in this case, but please note that I am not considering using any HTTP proxy(Apache, Nginx). I want machine B to forward things at the TCP level(I don't want to deal with SSL certificates)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use [rinetd](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rinetd).

"*rinetd redirects TCP connections from one IP address and port to another, with basic IP-based access control.rinetd is a single-process server which handles any number of connections to the address/port pairs specified in the file /etc/rinetd.conf. Since rinetd runs as a single process using nonblocking I/O, it is able to redirect a large number of connections without a severe impact on the machine.*"